# XSLT Get string length of CDATA section

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

I am looking for Some hints, Get the string length of Cdata element

```
<root>
<description><![CDATA[This handbook covers the major topics <b>in</b> Spanish, but is by no means complete.]]></description>
</root>
```

What I have tried so for, I am using **XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<xsl:variable name="Values">
<xsl:value-of select="root/description"  disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="string-length($Values)"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Total String length is **85** it includes `<b></b>`, But I need 79 except `<b></b>`.

Please let me have some ideas.

Comment: `disable-output-escaping` does not work inside variables so that is why you don't get the result you want. There is no easy way to solve this in XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 without extension functions.

Comment: If you want to treat the `<b></b>` as markup then why on earth are you putting it in a CDATA section? CDATA means "treat everything in here as text even if it looks like markup". That's what CDATA is for, and the only thing it is good for.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but it's 78:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="description">
  <xsl:call-template name="string-length" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="string-length">
  <xsl:param name="string" select="." />
  <xsl:param name="length" select="0" />

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string-length($string) = 0">
      <xsl:value-of select="$length" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="not(contains($string, '&lt;'))">
      <xsl:value-of select="$length + string-length($string)" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:variable
          name="before"
          select="string-length(substring-before($string, '&lt;'))" />
      <xsl:call-template name="string-length">
        <xsl:with-param name="string"
                        select="substring-after($string, '>')" />
        <xsl:with-param name="length"
                        select="$length + $before" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This won't handle a `<` that isn't followed by a `>`.

Now for the lecture:

- `<![CDATA[...]]>` is not an element.  The proper term is "CDATA section".  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-cdata-sect
- CDATA sections that escape markup that you actually want to process as markup are seldom (more likely, never) a good idea
- CDATA sections are useful for things like putting examples of markup into an XML document, but apart from that, don't use CDATA sections

Comment: This is a valiant effort, but it can easily fail because - unlike a proper XML parser - it cannot distinguish between markup and `<` and `>` characters that are part of the text. The proper solution in XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 is to disable output escaping, save the result to a file, then process the resulting file.

Comment: 'Valiant' is overstating it: 'quick and dirty' is closer to the truth. I had already stated that it won't work as is for unmatched `<` as well as warned against the whole idea of putting markup in CDATA sections and then trying to do something with it. Only the OP knows whether it's possible to have an unmatched `<` inside a CDATA section that's not represented as `&lt;` (or even `&#38;#60;`). We don't know why the OP wants to count characters, but if the OP had said that the element contained TeX markup and wanted to count characters outside of `{` and `}`, we'd have no qualms about helping.

Comment: You keep stressing "unmatched"; my point is that it can fail even if the `<` and `>` characters are matched, but do not represent  markup.

Comment: True, but we don't know if matched non-markup literal `<` and `>` can occur at all. If, as I suspect, the `description` contents came from a form, it's likely that the form software will properly escape literal `<` and `>`.  We just don't know. Doing stuff with markup inside CDATA sections is a really bad idea, but we don't know exactly how bad it is in this case. The solution as given will also count `&lt;` as four characters instead of one, but it's something that the OP can work with and improve.

Answer (score 0):

To do this cleanly you would need to switch to a processor supporting XPath 3 `parse-xml-fragment`(https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml-fragment) e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="string-length(parse-xml-fragment(root/description))"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Needs current versions of Saxon 9 or AltovaXML or Exselt.